# Entity-Relationship Model for Chat-Database

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I am creating an Application for my exam and I am implementing a chat-function. (As Simple As Possible)

Now I need to create an `Entity-Relationship-Model`

Therefore I have these entities:

`chatgroups` `chatmessages` and `chatusers`

I have created this ER-Model:

[image]

Can anyone please tell me if this is the correct way or if there is a more efficient or even better way to create this model?

**Best regards**

Comment: What have you tried? You should post what you have tried first, and then, if you hit a brick wall people can help. No one is going to do your exam for you unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model looks reasonable.  I'd advise you to underline your key attributes and to name at least your M:N relationship, e.g. subscriptions, since it must have its own table.  Naming the other two would be a good idea though they can be denormalized into the chatmessages entity relation.